# Nested UI Filter AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, filter, components

I'm looking for a way to define complex filters in the UI including nested filters and conditions. I know of SmartClient RIA that supports this (see screenshot), but requires us to use their framework. Before we start implementing our own I was wondering if anyone has a tip of an existing component backed by AngularJS that supports this type of setup?

[image: Advanced Filter Example]

Comment: requests like this are off topic here

Comment: Not to start a discussion here: If it is a generic question on how to design this, then the UX stack would be better, as this is very specific and similar questions are common here I would tend to disagree. Any feedback on how to improve or where to move it is appreciated in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

[Angular.js Query Builder](http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I had in mind, "query builder" being the key, went nuts looking for filter builder and similar phrases.